# n view controllers or n cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a scenario where the user is transformed to a new view controller `vc2` when he presses `add` button.

depending on where he came from, required fields will change. For instance, if he choose to add a **task** he should enter `title`, `due date` and `time`, but when he choose to add a **person** he should enter `contact info`.

Is it better to have two separate view controllers (`vc2a`,`vc2b`) or one table view controller `vc2` that contains prototype of all cells for the two case, but every time I call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I have to check from where I come.

for me as a developer it is easier to have different view controller in storyboard especially when n>2, but if that can make a difference in performance things will change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my opinion it is better to do this task in a single view controller, provided you are performing similar next action after adding a task of adding a person.

And instead of putting up the checks in cellForRowAtIndexPath because it is called multiple times do place a check in numberOfRowsInSection.

In numberOfRowsInSection do

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  OMGOrderDetailsSectionType sectionType = [[self.tableViewLayoutArray objectAtIndex:section] integerValue];

  if (sectionType == 0) {
    if(self.isContactsType) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  else if (sectionType == 1) {
    if(self.isTaskType) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Rest remains same for cellForRow, do configure both type of cells.

Comment: Yes, next action is similar. I already check in numberOfRowsInSection, because it differs. Do you mean (1) in addition to your code, in storyboard I should add two sections where section1 contains task cells and section2 contains person cells? (2) in cellForRowAtIndexPath I can ignore checking for section type?

Comment: Yes. Eventually in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can configure cells for both sections and the cells to be displayed will be managed by numberOfRowsInSection.